# Use ID file to replace some columns in dataset then print entire datset

Tags: dataframe, awk, sed, columnsorting

Still new to coding and having difficulty connecting commands to get the required output.

I have a data file in the following format:

```
NationalCowID,TestDate,Batch,LN,DIM,YBr,year,CH4,PLS,qtl
206004574,20141208,6,2,92,1,2014,424.4410055,NA,1
206004573,20141209,6,2,93,2,2014,436.4504712,NA,4
206004575,20141207,6,2,91,1,2014,380.94688,NA,6
206004576,20141208,6,2,92,2,2014,424.4410055,NA,7
206004579,20141209,6,2,93,2,2014,436.4504712,NA,8
206004571,20141207,6,2,91,1,2014,380.94688,NA,9
```

In the data, I would like to find the rows where the variable YBr == 1 and replace all columns in that row with * except for the NationalCowID or qtl. Then print the entire dataset.

This is what I am trying to achieve

```
NationalCowID,TestDate,Batch,LN,DIM,YBr,year,CH4,PLS,qtl
206004574,20141208,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,1
206004573,20141209,6,2,93,2,2014,436.4504712,NA,4
206004575,20141207,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,6
206004576,20141208,6,2,92,2,2014,424.4410055,NA,7
206004579,20141209,6,2,93,2,2014,436.4504712,NA,8
206004571,20141207,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,9
```

I've figured out to use sed and awk, but am struggling to go beyond the basics and use commands in combination:

```
awk -F ',' '{ if ($3 == 1) sed '{s/$0/*/g}' print $0}'}' file1 > file2
```

Any direction would be really appreciated!

Comment: Good that you have shown us your efforts in order to solve this question, always show expected output too in code tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't show us sample expected output so can't be sure about following. By this solution I am not hard coding field values of strings `YBr` or `NationalCowID` so it could be dynamic too. Could you please try following once.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=","
}
FNR==1{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i=="YBr"){
       field=i
    }
    if($i=="NationalCowID"){
       value=i
    }
  }
}
$field==1{
  for(i=value+1;i<=NF;i++){
       $i="*"
  }
}
1
' Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
NationalCowID,TestDate,Batch,LN,DIM,YBr,year,CH4,PLS,qtl
206004574,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*
206004573,20141209,6,2,93,2,2014,436.4504712,NA,4
206004575,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*
206004576,20141208,6,2,92,2,2014,424.4410055,NA,7
206004579,20141209,6,2,93,2,2014,436.4504712,NA,8
206004571,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*
```

Comment: Thank-you for your help! I will update my questions o this it includes an output file. I would like to keep the last column (qtl) as well as the first (NationalCowID). Which part of the code tells you what columns you are keeping or changing?

Comment: @Cae.rich, to keep the last column change `for` loop's value from `for(i=value+1;i<=NF;i++)` TO `for(i=value+1;i<=(NF-1);i++)` and let me know then?

Comment: @ RavinderSingh13 Worked perfectly! Thank-you so much for your help!